# How to customize the login error message?

Tags: django

I want to change "please enter a correct username and password. note that both fields may be case-sensitive" to something else.

In login.html I have `{{ form|crispy }}` and in urls.py I have `url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),` in my URLs.py.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to change from `auth.login` to a new subclass view of `auth.LoginView` with a subclass of `AuthenticationForm`.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }


class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    authentication_form = MyAuthForm
```

You can change the `invalid_login` entry as needed for your message.

In your urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$', MyLoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

@schillingt's answer is great.

I provide another answer, it may not be beautiful, but **if you are urgent** and you don't have any idea, at least this method (`contextmanager`) can help you work. It can be suitable in many cases since *django* uses a lot of class property to control something.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy


class LoginViewCustom(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'my_login.html'
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': gettext_lazy('...'),
        'inactive': gettext_lazy("..."),
    }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.handle_msg():
            rtn_response: TemplateResponse = super(LoginViewCustom, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return rtn_response

    @contextmanager
    def handle_msg(self):
        org_msg = AuthenticationForm.error_messages
        AuthenticationForm.error_messages = self.error_messages
        try:
            yield self.error_messages
        finally:
            AuthenticationForm.error_messages = org_msg
```